# Using Amazon MSK and Debezium SQL Server Connector. Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {TestKafkaDB= UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I was trying to connect my RDS MS SQL server with Debezium SQL Server Connector to stream changes to Kafka Cluster on Amazon MSK.

I configured connector and Kafka Connect worker well run the Connect by
`bin/connect-standalone.sh ../worker.properties connect/dbzmmssql.properties`

Got `WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 10 : {TestKafkaDB=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1031)`

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem and just want to share my possible solution with other fresher with Kafka.

`TestKafkaDB=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` basically means the connector didn't find the a usable topic in Kafka broker. The reason I am facing this is the Kafka broker didn't automatically create a new topic for the stream.

To solving this, I changed Cluster Configuration in AWS MSK console, change `auto.create.topics.enable` from default `false` to `true` and update this configuration to the Cluster, then my problem solved.

Comment: It's recommended to keep auto-topic creation disabled and instead create the topics before you make a source connector

Comment: for auto-topic creation, read [this reference](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/topic-auto-create-config.html)

Comment: Just to add that even you have created a configuration with auto-creation enabled, you may forget to use that configuration on the cluster.